# Error when trying to bind popup on geojson, failed to execute 'appendChild'

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

I'm trying to load more than 13 thousand points in leaflet from a geoJson file, everything seems to work just fine except the Popup function. I've looked everywhere for a solution and most answers out here do not work in my case. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
//calling the geoJSON    
        var SaoPaulo = L.geoJson(SP_ResSinglePoint, {

            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var popupContent = feature.properties.Time;
                console.log(popupContent);
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, Style(feature)).bindPopup(popupContent);
            },

        });
```

When I click on a given point I get the following message on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

But I do get all the info I'm looking for through the `console.log` so I'm assuming that that my popup parameters are correct, but yet no luck in the map.

Comment: What type is feature.properties.Time? It seems that the popup content needs to be in string type

Comment: ... This was exactly the issue! I had no clue that popup could only take string values, does the documentation mention this at all?

Comment: @RicardoOliveira The [leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bindpopup) shows it can take a string, html element, or an already created popup object.

Comment: @AlexandruPufan post as answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and it solved when I concatenated a string to it.

```
// the number shows correctly itself
console.log(layer.feature.properties.ROWID); // 46

// but bindPopup() won't accept numbers
layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.ROWID); // error

// Then you must convert to string 
layer.bindPopup('quartier ' + layer.feature.properties.ROWID); // working fine
```

Comment: This is a nice trick.

Comment: The problem is that it requires the content to be a string, it won't automatically convert it. The proper way is to cast the parameter into a string using String(param) e.g. layer.bindPopup(String(param));

Comment: I had used .toString() to solve this today. If you don't need a label in front of the value, it could be helpful. In the example above, it would be: `layer.bindPopup (layer.feature.properties.ROWID.toString());`